# How to show `\` instead of special character `₩` in path separator for Windows Forms text-box?

Tags: winforms, utf-8, cjk

My Windows Forms app displays a file path in a text-box.  For our customers in Korea, this is shown as `C:₩Users₩abc123₩my₩path` instead of `C:\Users\abc123\my\path`.  However, their command prompts, PowerShell instances, Windows Explorer versions etc. all show `\` for the path separator.

I understand that I want to use UTF-8 as the character encoding; but I haven't set it explicitly anywhere in my code, so I presumed the encoding was UTF-8 by default.

I think I might need to do something [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) but I'm not sure how to do it for Windows Forms where there doesn't seem to be an `ActiveCodePage` property.

Comment: I am a Korean developer. In Korea, we use ₩ and \ interchangeably, so it doesn't matter what you write, it means the same thing. On Windows OS, it will only display as ₩ regardless of the font, but you don't need to worry about that. This is because the ASCII value ₩ (5C) is replaced by / in Korean fonts. This is also true for UTF-8, which has compatibility with ASCII (LSB 1 byte is the same as ASCII). I don't know if there's a way to force it to be only ₩ or only \, but at least from a Korean perspective, it doesn't matter if it's ₩ or \ or both.

Comment: @eloiz - thank you!  I was wondering whether this was actually a problem or not; so that's extremely useful information.  I'll leave it alone, then.

Comment: Historical reading: https://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.html